# What is "Upgrade from VC 7.1" property sheet?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm porting a project from MSVS2005 to MSVS2010. I just loaded the solution in MSVS2010 and let the wizard convert the projects.

I ran into the property manager and found these property sheets (top-to-bottom):

- Upgrade from VC 7.1
- Microsoft.Cpp.x64(or Win32).user
- Multi-byte Character Support (not editable)
- Dynamic Link to MFC (not editable)

I understand the last three ones but I don't know what is the purpose of **Upgrade from VC 7.1**. Can someone give me a little explanation?

---

P.S. I found C/C++, Preprocessor, Preprocessor Definitions = **_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)** in property page "Upgrade from VC 7.1" but in project properties I see **NDEBUG;WIN32;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)**. What does all this mean? What is the **_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710** macro?

Comment: Seems like some legacy properties that have no 2010 equivalent but are too important to simply drop them silently.

Comment: Possible but look at the P.S. I added. What is **_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710** that is not propagated in project properties?

Comment: Regarding your edit, [this could help a little bit regarding `_VC80_UPGRADE`](http://www.windowsdesktopdev.com/visual-c-general/win32-windows-vc80upgrade--what-do-they-meando-65941.shtml), maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A project property sheet simply pre-sets settings for a project.  Unless the project overrides the setting.  Which your project does, it overrides the "Preprocessor Definitions" setting.  The extra "%(PreprocessorDefinitions)" macro ensures that the definitions from the property sheets are *appended* and not lost.

So the definitions that the compiler sees are `NDEBUG;WIN32;_LIB;_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710`

The _VC80_UPGRADE macro helps your old project to compile and run correctly on Visual Studio version 2005 or later.  It is used, for one, in vc/atlmfc/include/afxres.h to ensure that the manifest resource has the correct ID.

You are skipping many VS and Windows versions so this doesn't exactly mean you'll have no problems at all.  Particularly UAC can give you a headache.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the answer. I appreciate particularly the **%(...)** explanation.